Why is the bloc listener not called even when its a success state?
Here is the code snippet:
body: MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => StripeProductCollectionCubit(
                    productId: productModel.selfRef.id,
                    collectionRef: context
                        .read<FirestoreRepository>()
                        .firestore
                        .collection('stripeProducts')),
              ),
              BlocProvider(create: (context) => StripeCheckoutCubit())
            ],
            child: BlocListener<StripeCheckoutCubit, StripeCheckoutState>(
              listener: (context, state) async {
                if (state
                    is StripeCheckoutInitiationSuccess<CheckoutSessionModel>) {
                  final checkoutModelUrl = state.checkoutData.url;
                  final launchCheckoutUrl = Uri.parse(checkoutModelUrl);
                  if (await canLaunchUrl(launchCheckoutUrl)) {
                    launchUrl(launchCheckoutUrl,
                        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
                  } else {
                    debugPrint('Cannot launch website Url');
                  }
                }
              },

Why is bloc listener not being called? The state emits success, which was verified.
part of 'stripe_checkout_cubit.dart';

sealed class StripeCheckoutState {}

final class StripeCheckoutInitial extends StripeCheckoutState {}

final class StripeCheckoutInitiationSuccess<T extends Equatable>
    extends StripeCheckoutState {
  final CheckoutSessionModel checkoutData;

  StripeCheckoutInitiationSuccess(this.checkoutData);
}

final class StripeCheckoutInitiationError extends StripeCheckoutState {
  final String message;
  StripeCheckoutInitiationError(this.message);
}



  Future<void> _listenToCheckoutSessions(
      {required DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> checkoutRef}) async {
    debugPrint('_listentTocheckoutreached');
    try {
      var stream = checkoutRef.snapshots();
      _sub?.cancel();
      _sub = stream.listen((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
        debugPrint('entering snapshot function');
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          debugPrint('snapshot exists');
          emit(
            StripeCheckoutInitiationSuccess(
                CheckoutSessionModel.fromSnapshot(snapshot)),
          );
        }
      });
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      emit(StripeCheckoutInitiationError(e.toString()));
      await Sentry.captureException(e, stackTrace: stackTrace);
    }
  }

The state is emitting success, but the bloc listener is not called when the state is updated. Should there be be a listenWhen field for blocListener?The state is emitting success, but the bloc listener is not called when the state is updated. Should there be be a listenWhen field for blocListener?
